# Building a Custom Report from a saved search using the "Advanced PDF/Template" Editor

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

I'm building a printable Report based off a saved search to group and subtotal multiple Lots and inventory Detail listing it under each item and displaying the subtotal below each group of items.

I can format the code properly to display 1 item at a time using this

```
    <#if results?has_content>
<table class="itemtable" dir="ltr" style="width:100%;"><!-- start items --><#list results as result><tr>
    <td style="width: 43px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">**</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 70px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.itemid}</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 94px; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.displayname}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 133px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 72px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 47px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 120px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 43px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custitempacksize}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 70px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custcol_lottextitemlinelevel}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 48px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custitem_brand}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 94px;">${result.expirationdate}</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.serialnumbers}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 133px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.location}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 72px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custbodyestimatedarrivaldate}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 47px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.rate}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.formulacurrency}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 79px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.quantityavailable}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 68px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.formulanumeric}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 43px;">**</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="1" style="width: 70px;">Subtotal for :&nbsp;${result.itemid}</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 133px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 72px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 47px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 120px;">&nbsp;
    <hr />{subtotalEC}</td>
    <td style="width: 79px;">&nbsp;
    <hr />{subtotalLB}</td>
    <td style="width: 68px;">&nbsp;
    <hr />{subtotalCS}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list><!-- end items --></table>
</#if>
</body>
</pdf>
```

I'm on the right track to getting the results I want in the PDF but when I Attempt to add <#if> and <#else> tags to group the items It will save but then generate an Unexpected Error when I attempt to print it.

```
<pdf>
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <macrolist>
        <macro id="nlheader">
            ${preferences.formlandscape}
<table class="header" style="width:100%;"><tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; height: 40px; width: 178px;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Date:</strong></span></td>
    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap; height: 40px; width: 400px;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Hofseth North America<br />In Stock Inventory Report sorted by Item<br />For All Items Available All Locations</strong></span></td>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; height: 40px;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Page:<pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></strong></span></td>
    </tr></table>

<table boarder="1" class="header" style="width:100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="width: 40px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Pack Size</span></th>
    <th style="width: 55px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Load #</span></th>
    <th style="width: 75px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Brand</span></th>
    <th style="width: 50px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Exp. Date</span></th>
    <th style="width: 90px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Lot #</span></th>
    <th style="width: 100px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Location</span></th>
    <th style="width: 65px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Arrival<br />Date</span></th>
    <th style="width: 69px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Unit<br />Cost</span></th>
    <th style="width: 110px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Extended<br />Cost</span></th>
    <th style="width: 70px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Qty<br />Available</span></th>
    <th style="width: 64px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Units<br />Available</span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
        </macro>
    </macrolist>
    <style type="text/css">* {
                        <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
                            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKsc, sans-serif;
                        <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
                            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKtc, sans-serif;
                        <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
                            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKjp, sans-serif;
                        <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
                            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKkr, sans-serif;
                        <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
                            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansThai, sans-serif;
                        <#else>
                            font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
                        </#if>
}
        table {
            font-size: 9pt;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 8pt;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 5px 6px 3px;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            color: #333333;
        }
        td {
            padding: 4px 6px;
        }
        td p { align:left }
</style>
</head> 
    <body header="nlheader" header-height="15%" padding="0.2in 0.2in 0.2in 0.2in" size="Letter-LANDSCAPE">
    <#if results?has_content><#assign subtotalEC = 0 subtotalLB = 0 subtotalCS = 0>
<table class="itemtable" style="width:100%;"><!-- start items --><#list results as result><#list result.itemid as items>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 43px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">**</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 70px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.itemid}</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 94px; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.displayname}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 133px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 72px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 47px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 120px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 79px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 68px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<#elseif><tr>
    <td style="width: 43px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custitempacksize}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 70px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custcol_lottextitemlinelevel}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 48px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custitem_brand}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 94px;">${result.expirationdate}</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.serialnumbers}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 133px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.location}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 72px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.custbodyestimatedarrivaldate}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 47px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.rate}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 120px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.formulacurrency}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 79px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.quantityavailable}</span></td>
    <td style="width: 68px;"><span style="font-size:10px;">${result.formulanumeric}</span></td>
    </tr>
    </#elseif></#list>
    <#else><tr>
    <td style="width: 43px;">**</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="1" style="width: 70px;">Subtotal for :&nbsp;${result.itemid}</td>
    <td style="width: 97px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 133px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 72px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 47px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 120px;">&nbsp;
    <hr />{subtotalEC}</td>
    <td style="width: 79px;">&nbsp;
    <hr />{subtotalLB}</td>
    <td style="width: 68px;">&nbsp;
    <hr />{subtotalCS}</td>
    </tr>
    </#else></#list><!-- end items --></table>
</#if>
</body>
</pdf>
```

I cannot get it to create the list I want using freemarker tags. 
The code I've supplied saves with no errors 
but then generates an unknown error when trying to print 
or display it as PDF from the UI.

I would like the following to happen.

Have the report Group and list all items. 
Under each Item List the Line level detailed information contained in the search from that item. 
Subtotal 3 fields from the Grouped Info under each item and display it  under the last Line of Grouped Information.
Then repeat for all items contained in the search

Answer (score 0):

It might be finicky about your if-else structure.
You are closing the tags for the else-ifs and else's, where it might not like that.
Here's an example from the freemarker website:

> <#if x == 1>
>     x is 1
>   <#elseif x == 2>
>     x is 2
>   <#elseif x == 3>
>     x is 3
>   <#elseif x == 4>
>     x is 4
>   <#else>
>     x is not 1 nor 2 nor 3 nor 4
>    < /#if>

Worth a try!